# Kendo upload - how to add a javascript event handler for file remove button click

Tags: kendo-ui, synchronous, kendo-upload

My kendo template is as follows:

```html
<div id="file-err-msg" > Please remove files with errors</div>
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
<script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class='k-progress'>
    </span>
    <strong class='k-upload-status'>
        <button type='button' class='btn-remove k-button k-button-bare k-upload-action'> 
            <span class='k-icon k-i-close k-delete' title='Remove'></span>
        </button>
    </strong>
</script>
<script>
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
        template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html())
    });
</script>
```

I need to hide the div with id - file-err-msg, when the remove button is clicked. the Remove action is happening when the span with css class "k-delete" is clicked. I need to add the below event handler in addition, and it is never being called.

```js
$(".k-delete").click(function () {
    alert("Remove button clicked");
});
```

since these controls are rendered dynamically, i tried to bind them to the event handler as below, but nothing works.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-remove", function () {
    alert("dynamic control event handler");
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Kendo Upload API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-remove), you can bind a function to the `remove` event.
So this is where you could hide your `file-err-msg` div :

```js
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html()),
    remove: function(e) {
        $('#file-err-msg').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe the remove event only works if the upload widget is async.